# In Python, is it possible to iterate over values stored in a thread local by each thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, thread-local

Suppose I have this:

```
from threading import local
tl = local()
```

At various points, different threads in a thread pool will set something on the thread local:

```
tl.resource = <something>
```

Is it possible to iterate over all tl.resource set by each thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not in Python, although you *might* be able to dig around in the interpreter state in C and acquire this information (although I doubt it).  It would be reasonable to assume that this might be possible if `local()` returned a singleton for each thread, but **it does not** - calling `local()` multiple times in the same thread will generate multiple unique thread-local storage instances (not return a reference to the same object) and as such there is not a single field in the Python internal thread structure that holds this data, making it difficult to inspect.